# Best C# implementation of IndexOfAny(string, params string[])

Tags: c#, performance, strings, search

[Follow-Up question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/225220/29371)

.Net provides `String.IndexOfAny(string, char[])` but not `String.IndexOfAny(string, string[])`.

The existing built-in `String.IndexOfAny` takes an array of `char` and returns the lowest position of any one `char` from the array in a passed in `string` or `-1` if none are found. Essentially it is the `char` equivalent of my naive definition.

My extension takes a `string` to search `s` and an array of `string`s to find `targets` and returns the lowest position found of any member of `targets` in `s` or `-1` if none are found.

A naive implementation (using LINQ) isn't particularly efficient:

```
public static int IndexOfAny1(this string s, params string[] targets) =>
    targets.Select(t => s.IndexOf(t)).Where(p => p >= 0).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).Min();
```

My improved implementation tracks the current candidate position and restricts future searches to be before that candidate position:

```
public static int IndexOfAny2(this string s, params string[] targets) {
    int? curAns = null;
    foreach (var target in targets) {
        var posAns = s.IndexOf(target, 0, curAns.HasValue ? curAns.Value + target.Length : s.Length);

        if (posAns >= 0 && (!curAns.HasValue || posAns < curAns)) {
            curAns = posAns;
            if (curAns == 0) // once you're at the beginning, can't be any less
                break;
        }
    }

    return curAns ?? -1;
}
```

This runs up to two times faster.

Sample code to test the two methods:

```
Console.WriteLine($"IndexOfAny1 should be 8: {"foo bar baz".IndexOfAny1("barz", "baz")}");
Console.WriteLine($"IndexOfAny1 should be 0: {"aabbccddeeffgghh".IndexOfAny1("bbb", "hh", "aa")}");
Console.WriteLine($"IndexOfAny2 should be 8: {"foo bar baz".IndexOfAny2("barz", "baz")}");
Console.WriteLine($"IndexOfAny2 should be 0: {"aabbccddeeffgghh".IndexOfAny2("bbb", "hh", "aa")}");
```

Is there a better algorithm or another way to make this faster?

PS Test harness for testing random possibilities:

```
var r = new Random();

var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int j1 = 0; j1 < r.Next(80,160); ++j1)
    sb.Append((char)('0'+r.Next(0, 26+52)));
var s = sb.ToString();

var listTargets = new List<string>();
for (int j1 = 0; j1 < r.Next(5, 10); ++j1)
    if (r.NextDouble() < 0.8) {
        var tLen = r.Next(4, Math.Min(s.Length - 4, 10));
        var beginPos = r.Next(0, s.Length - tLen);
        listTargets.Add(s.Substring(beginPos, tLen));
    }
    else {
        sb.Clear();
        for (int j2 = 0; j2 < r.Next(5, 10); ++j2)
            sb.Append((char)('0'+r.Next(0, 26+52)));
        listTargets.Add(sb.ToString());
    }

var targets = listTargets.ToArray();
if (s.IndexOfAny1(targets) != s.IndexOfAny2(targets))
    Console.WriteLine($"Fail on {s} containing {String.Join(",", targets)}");
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 6):

#### Review

- Don't use abbreviated variable names `s`, `curAns` and `posAns`; use self describing names: `value`, `index` and `targetIndex` instead.
- The nullable int could be replaced with `-1`. This reads cleaner and allows you to bypass the final `??` operator in `curAns ?? -1`.
- You can optimize the count `curAns.Value + target.Length` with adding `-1` because we don't care about finding another match on the currently best found index.
- You should exit early if no targets are specified

#### Refactored

```
public static int IndexOfAny2(this string value, params string[] targets)
{
    var index = -1;
    if (targets == null || targets.Length == 0) return index;

    foreach (var target in targets)
    {
        var targetIndex = value.IndexOf(target, 0, 
            index > -1 ? index + target.Length - 1 : value.Length);

        if (targetIndex >= 0 && (index == -1 || targetIndex < index))
        {
            index = targetIndex;
            if (index == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but not really helpful to my question. BTW, I don't find `value` any more compelling than `s`. Perhaps its leaks from my database knowledge, but I think using `-1` to mean `index` has no value yet is bad practice - don't use magic values when coding. If I were designing it today, `IndexOf` would return an `int?` instead.

Comment: Why avoid the most well known magic number (index = -1) to use it anyway at return time?

Comment: Just a matter of style or preference I guess.

Comment: I improved my `IndexOfAny2` based on your comments and added at bottom of question. Thanks for the improvements, though still not getting at the root of my question.

Answer (score 1):

- `"abc".IndexOfAny2("c", "abc")` fails with an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, because `IndexOf` requires `startIndex + count` to not exceed the length of the string.
- For a tiny improvement, make `curAns` a normal integer and initialize it with `s.Length`. After the necessary changes, you'll end up with fewer checks inside the `foreach` loop.

Most time is spent in `string.IndexOf` however, so for more substantial improvements you'll want to investigate more optimized (and more complex) algorithms such as Rabin-Karp, Knuth-Morris-Pratt, Boyer-Moore, Aho-Corasick, etc.

Comment: I would assume based on the reference source that `String.IndexOf` being a C intrinsic is either using a direct x64 instruction or is implementing a high speed optimized algorithm already (it calls the kernel32 `FindNLSString` function). However, this did lead me to add `StringComparison.Ordinal` to my `IndexOf` call, which added some speed.

Comment: Added a bug fix version of the bottom of my question, thanks for the bug report. I like your `s.Length` suggestion as the code looks nice but in practice it runs fractionally slower even with fewer tests.

Comment: @NetMage: As far as I could [find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2584204/263535), `IndexOf` is doing a 'naive' search. Good point about `StringComparison.Ordinal`, but it depends on what behavior you need. For example, a culture-specific comparison can match `"é"` against `"é"` (which is `"e\u0301"` - an 'e' followed by a combining accent), an ordinal comparison won't. I'd make it a parameter instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: I did so, but of course, I can't put the improved code anywhere in a way I would like. I may ask another question with working code... BTW, I am not sure that the .Net Core usage matches the .Net Framework call to the kernel function.

Comment: I'd assume that if `FindNLSString` was using a better algorithm, they would've ported it to .Net Core, given how much they're focusing on performance, but without access to the actual source there's no way to be sure.

Comment: Well, the problem is .Net Core must work on MacOS/Linux, so it can't call the Windows Kernel...

Comment: They could still have ported the algorithm. Anyway, regarding `s.Length`, I did some more testing, and the results are very hit-and-miss. After comparing the fastest runs I think there's no significant difference (on my system anyway). That's interesting, because the IL is twice as short. I suppose the JITter is doing a good job with nullables.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if .Net developers don't have access to Windows source code.