# String.IndexOfAny(string, string[]) (lowest position for group of needles in haystack)

Tags: c#, performance, strings, search

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/224980/5846) with bug fixes, question and code improvements from @dfhwze, @PieterWitvoet, @HenrikHansen, @t3chb0t. I am still hoping for an improved approach or algorithm rather than micro-optimizations to the code.

.Net provides `String.IndexOfAny(string, char[])` but not `String.IndexOfAny(string, string[])`.

The existing built-in `String.IndexOfAny` takes an array of `char` and returns the lowest position of any one `char` from the array in a passed in `string` or `-1` if none are found.

My extension takes a `string` to search `s` and an array of `string`s to find `targets` and returns the lowest position found of any member of `targets` in `s` or `-1` if none are found.

A naive implementation (using LINQ) isn't particularly efficient:

```
public static int IndexOfAny1(this string s, params string[] targets) =>
    targets.Select(t => s.IndexOf(t)).Where(p => p >= 0).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).Min();
```

My improved implementation tracks the current candidate position and restricts future searches to be before that candidate position:

```
public static int IndexOfAny2(this string s, params string[] targets) => s.IndexOfAny3(StringComparison.Ordinal, targets);
public static int IndexOfAny2(this string s, StringComparison sc, params string[] targets) {
    if (targets == null || targets.Length == 0)
        return -1;

    int index = s.IndexOf(targets[0], sc);
    var sLen = s.Length;

    for (int j1 = 1; j1 < targets.Length; ++j1) {
        var target = targets[j1];
        var targetIndex = s.IndexOf(target, 0, index >= 0 ? Math.Min(sLen, index + target.Length) : sLen, sc);

        if (targetIndex >= 0 && (index == -1 || targetIndex < index)) {
            index = targetIndex;
            if (index == 0) // once you're at the beginning, can't be any less
                break;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```

This runs up to two times faster.

Sample code to test the two methods:

```
Console.WriteLine($"IndexOfAny1 should be 8: {"foo bar baz".IndexOfAny1("barz", "baz")}");
Console.WriteLine($"IndexOfAny1 should be 0: {"aabbccddeeffgghh".IndexOfAny1("bbb", "hh", "aa")}");
Console.WriteLine($"IndexOfAny1 should be 0: {"abc".IndexOfAny1("c", "abc")}");

Console.WriteLine($"IndexOfAny2 should be 8: {"foo bar baz".IndexOfAny2("barz", "baz")}");
Console.WriteLine($"IndexOfAny2 should be 0: {"aabbccddeeffgghh".IndexOfAny2("bbb", "hh", "aa")}");
Console.WriteLine($"IndexOfAny2 should be 0: {"abc".IndexOfAny2("c", "abc")}");
```

Is there a better algorithm or another way to make this faster?

PS Test harness for testing random possibilities:

```
var r = new Random();

var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int j1 = 0; j1 < r.Next(80,160); ++j1)
    sb.Append((char)('0'+r.Next(0, 26+52)));
var s = sb.ToString();

var listTargets = new List<string>();
for (int j1 = 0; j1 < r.Next(5, 10); ++j1)
    if (r.NextDouble() < 0.8) {
        var tLen = r.Next(4, Math.Min(s.Length - 4, 10));
        var beginPos = r.Next(0, s.Length - tLen);
        listTargets.Add(s.Substring(beginPos, tLen));
    }
    else {
        sb.Clear();
        for (int j2 = 0; j2 < r.Next(5, 10); ++j2)
            sb.Append((char)('0'+r.Next(0, 26+52)));
        listTargets.Add(sb.ToString());
    }

var targets = listTargets.ToArray();
if (s.IndexOfAny1(targets) != s.IndexOfAny2(targets))
    Console.WriteLine($"Fail on {s} containing {String.Join(",", targets)}");
```

Comment: As mentioned before, there are certainly better algorithms, but it also depends on the intended use-case. Many of the more advanced algorithms require some kind of preprocessing, which makes them slower for small inputs, but faster for larger inputs, more targets, repeated searches, and so on. What exactly are your requirements?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I would say short text, small list of targets would be typical use case: think processing lines of text from a file. Note my test harness generates 80 - 160 character strings and 5 - 10 targets of upto 10 characters, 80% found.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you've managed to fix the algorithm, so it does what it's supposed to do. But the concept is the same and performance isn't improved.

Still you could use some more descriptive names, and `i` instead of `j1` (why `1`?).

You could use `foreach (string target in targets) { ... }` instead of `for (int j1;...)` because you don't use the index to anything and the performance for an array is about the same for the two `for`-concepts.

---

You ask for other algorithm types that improves performance.

One concept for the algorithm - that seems to improve the performance significantly - could be the following:

```
public static int IndexOfAny(this string text, params string[] targets)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return -1;
  if (targets == null || targets.Length == 0) return -1;

  for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
  {
    foreach (string target in targets)
    {
      if (i + target.Length <= text.Length && target == text.Substring(i, target.Length))
        return i;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

---

Another that can improve performance even more is the following written in pseudo code - leaving it as a challenge for you to implement it in C#:

```
IndexOfAny text targets:
    for i = 0 to len(text)-1:
        skip = len(text)
        foreach target in targets:
            target_can_skip = 0
            for k = 0 to len(target)-1:
                if target[k] <> text[i+k]:
                    target_can_skip = count how many chars that can be skipped in text before target can be a candidate again
                    break
            if k == len(target):
                return i


            skip = min(skip, target_can_skip)

        if skip > 0: 
            i = i + skip - 1

    return -1 // No match found
```

---

Besides that you may find inspiration [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm)

---

**Update according to VisualMelons comments:**

The above implemented with `string.IndexOf()`:

```
public static int IndexOfAny1(this string text, params string[] targets)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return -1;
  if (targets == null || targets.Length == 0) return -1;

  for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
  {
    foreach (string target in targets)
    {
      if (i + target.Length <= text.Length && text.IndexOf(target, i, target.Length) == i)
        return i;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Notice that the `count` parameter must be at minimum the length of `target` or else it will not be found.

Test case:

```
  Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
  IndexOfAnyDelegate[] funcs = new IndexOfAnyDelegate[]
  {
    Extensions.IndexOfAny,
    //Extensions.IndexOfAny1,
  };

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
      foreach (var func in funcs)
      {
        sum += func("foo bar baz", "foo", "barz", "baz", " ");
        sum += func("aabbccddeeffgghh", "bbb", "hh", "aaa", "fg");
        sum += func("abcabc", "c", "abc");
        sum += func("abcabc", "x", "wer");
        sum += func("adfaææwjerqijaæsdklfjaeoirweqærqkljadfaewrwexwer", "xxxxx", "yyyyy", "zzzzz", "Aaaaaa", "x", "wer");

        //Console.WriteLine($"IndexOfAny should be 8: {func("foo bar baz", "barz", "baz", " ", "foo")}");
        //Console.WriteLine($"IndexOfAny should be 0: {func("aabbccddeeffgghh", "bbb", "hh", "aaa", "fg")}");
        //Console.WriteLine($"IndexOfAny should be 0: {func("abcabc", "c", "abc")}");
        //Console.WriteLine($"IndexOfAny should be 0: {func("abcabc", "x", "wer")}");
        //Console.WriteLine(func("adfaææwjerqijaæsdklfjaeoirweqærqkljadfaewrwexwer", "xxxxx", "yyyyy", "zzzzz", "Aaaaaa", "x", "wer"));
        //Console.WriteLine();
      }
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
    Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

You'll have to comment in/out as needed.

---

**Update 2**

The performance of the above pseudo code decreases (obviously) when the number of targets increases. So my analysis wasn't quite good enough. To optimize on that problem the below variant maintains an array of the next valid index per target, which minimize the number of targets that should be examined per char in the text string:

```
public static int IndexOfAny(this string text, params string[] targets)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return -1;
  if (targets == null || targets.Length == 0) return -1;

  // Holds the next valid index in text per parget.
  int[] targetNextIndex = new int[targets.Length];

  for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < targets.Length; j++)
    {
      // If the targets next index isn't i then continue to next target
      if (targetNextIndex[j] > i)
        continue;

      string target = targets[j];
      int k = 0;

      for (; k < target.Length && i + k < text.Length; k++)
      {
        if (target[k] != text[i + k])
        {
          int nextIndex = i + 1;
          // Tries to find the next index in text where the char equals the first char in target.
          while (nextIndex < text.Length && target[0] != text[nextIndex])
          {
            nextIndex++;
          }
          // The next valid index for the target is found, so save it
          targetNextIndex[j] = nextIndex;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (k == target.Length)
      {
        return i;
      }
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Comment: That middle algorithm is of course going to perform much better in some cases, but it needn't allocate anything: you can use `text.IndexOf(target,i,1) == i` (or something like that) instead of `target == text.Substring(i, target.Length)`

Comment: @VisualMelon: normally you are right, when writing something, but in this case - according to my test cases - using `IndexOf()` as you suggest instead of `Substring()` is about 10x slower.

Comment: Wow; glad you measured it then! Could you provide your test code in a gist or something (so I don't have to write my own), because I'm going to have to investigate why (makes no sense to me).

Comment: @VisualMelon: You are right: using `StringComparison.Ordinal` definitely improves performance.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure it's correct; I'm ashamed I can't remember what `==` does... (I never use it when globalisation is concerned)

Comment: I can't seem to find documentation for the exact behaviour of `==`, but it does appear to be ordinal (ends up calling `EqualsHelper` [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/referencesource/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs)), so it probably should be `Ordinal` for comparison. With that change, it runs your sample on my machine in ~60ms rather than ~100ms for the `SubString` version (and indeed 1s for the non-ordinal version!).

Comment: A bit of testing indicates that a for loop would be several times faster than the `Substring` approach (and indeed, `IndexOf` is significantly slower, for whatever reason). OP's solution is very sensitive to the order of `targets` - it works best if the first target(s) are found early on. Your solution works best if any target occurs early on, but it's slower when there are no matches at all.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet: If I understand you right, the for-loop approach is what I suggest in the pseudo code - which - when implemented - in fact is much faster than the others. I'm aware that worst case is different for the different algorithms.

Comment: `for` in general is faster than `foreach` when dealing with arrays (and `List`), and using `for` allowed for testing the first target separately to initialize `target` to something useful, which would be even slower with `foreach`. I don't use `i` as a general rule from an old habit of `i` and `l` being poor variables names since they are too easily mistaken for `1` or each other, but I had intended to change `j1` (my goto loop variable) with a more meaningful name (`targetIndex`?). I will try your suggested algorithms but they need to support `StringComparison`.

Comment: @VisualMelon `IndexOf` is only about 3 times slower in my (random) testing, but surprising to me as well. I wonder how .Net Core `Span` would be faster and avoid allocation. Perhaps `Substring` shares storage with the parent string when not a duplicate (interning)? PS I am familiar with the Wikipedia page, but assume (and have seen evidence) `IndexOf` is going to be faster than a C# implementation of any of those.

Comment: @HenrikHansen: ah yes, you're right. The `skip` variable threw me off, making me think it was some kind of Boyer-Moore variant.

Comment: My implementation of your pseudo-code uses `target_can_skip = k+1` which in my initial thinking seems correct (unless it is supposed to be based on all `targets` - I'm thinking the description is wrong otherwise it should affect `k` during the loop). Unfortunately there is a bug in the code when a match runs off the end of `text`: "abc".IndexOfAny("cd")`.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I think it is like BM, but since the comparison is not reversed, it is not as efficient at skipping (?).

Comment: @NetMage: whether `IndexOf` is faster than those algorithms depends on the use-case. For example, Aho-Corasick's preprocessing can be quite slow, but once that's done a multi-string search can be orders of magnitude faster. Even a single search can be faster if the search text contains few or no matches or if the search text is huge.

Comment: @NetMage: I think so, yes. Also, skipping normally relies on a pre-calculated skip table to be efficient, so I'm not sure what Henrik has in mind?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet A quick search shows a C# implementation of A-C says IndexOf is faster then you have less than 70 targets to look for, which implies to me it is not worth it for most use cases.

Comment: Forgot to mention, my implementation of your pseudo-code is 8 to 20 times faster than my naive method, so it is definitely a good improvement if it can be fixed.

Comment: @HenrikHansen: after testing it a bit, it looks like the next-index search is often actually slower, at least with OP's test data. Replacing the `while` loop with a `string.IndexOf(char, int)` makes it faster, but it's still occasionally slower compared to the same implementation, but with the next-index search removed. It's making the algorithm more susceptible to non-occurring targets, so maybe capping the look-ahead distance would be better.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet: OK, I think the (or my) conclusion is: the different variations over my pseudo code - with or without look ahead - takes the lead depending on the input. Compared the original and the `Substring()` approach, all my tests show them to be better.

Comment: I wonder if using `IndexOfAny(string,char[])` with the first characters of all targets would speed up finding the next possible match.